# Why does this prove that Leibniz series' are convergent?

Tags: calculus

[image: lecture]

I'm going through my old calculus notes and found this. Why is this a valid proof? The implication from the inequalities is that $S_{2n+1} \leq S_{2n-1} \leq S_{2n} \leq S_{2n+2}$. That means, $[S_{2n-1},S_{2n}] \subseteq [S_{2n+1},S_{2n+2}]$. Also, $a_n \rightarrow 0$, so I don't see how does Cantor axiom (theorem?) work here.

Comment: Which part exactly don't you understand ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe if we would like to use the cantor axiom, then instead of $[S_{2n-1},S_{2n}] \subseteq [S_{2n+1},S_{2n+2}]$, we need $[S_{2n-1},S_{2n}] \supseteq [S_{2n+1},S_{2n+2}]$, along with $a_n \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: You are right. The inequalities are incorrect. The correct inequalities are $S_{2n} \leq S_{2n+2} \leq S_{2n+1} \leq S_{2n-1}$.